# First Line x-repeat Background Image with css

Tags: css

I'd like to display a background image using background-image prop of css for only in first line of the page. How could I do this? I use a code like;

```
background-image:url(backgr.png);
background-repeat:x-repeat;
background-position:left top;
```

but this provides repeating the image in all lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this css:

```
background:url(backgr.png) repeat-x left top;
```

Comment: this will go over his head...just explain him that it's a short hand property ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about first line of the page, consider making a div with a proper height and width. You should place your image over there.

```
<html>
<head>
   <style type="text/css">
      body
      {
         background-image:url('yourimage.jpg');
         background-repeat:repeat-x;
      }
   </style>
</head>

<body>
   <p>Your text over here</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had thought to place a div. I was looking for a handy css technic. Thanks.